# COUNTIF phpexcel Wrong number of arguments

Tags: phpexcel

I'm using formulas in phpexcel and I have a problem using the countif

```
Wrong number of arguments for COUNTIFS() function: 4 given, 2 expected
```

But in the documentation countif is:

```
COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)
```

I have for exemple:

```
COUNTIFS(C$17:D$46,$B55,C$16:D$45,$B55)
```

It works when I directly use it on excel, is there a way to catch the error and keep the formula ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the definition of COUNTIFS in the /Classes/PHPExcel/Calculation.php file (around lines 499 to 502).

Currently it reads:

```
'COUNTIFS' => array('category' => PHPExcel_Calculation_Function::CATEGORY_STATISTICAL,
                    'functionCall' => 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::DUMMY',
                    'argumentCount' => '2'
              ),
```

add a comma after the argument count to make it

```
'COUNTIFS' => array('category' => PHPExcel_Calculation_Function::CATEGORY_STATISTICAL,
                    'functionCall' => 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Functions::DUMMY',
                    'argumentCount' => '2,'
              ),
```

Note that the COUNTIFS() function isn't actually implemented, so you can't do a getCalculatedValue() on any cell using the function to get the correct result, but it will then save correctly using the Excel2007 Writer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you say I have an error in the logs on getCalculatedValue(), I'm using $sheet->setCellValue(); to set the value is there a way to put the formula without calculating ?

Comment: You can set the value without calculating; but PHPExcel will calculate on a save unless you set preCalculateFormulas to FALSE for the writer.... note that autosize columns also force a calculation

Answer (score 0):

COUNTIFS in phpexcel is not yet implemented.